# Openedge 10.2 X-document node attributes order

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

Is there a way in OE to set the order for a node attributes?

I need this result:

```
<MyNode MyNode="aaa" Attribute1="bbb" Attribute2="ccc" Attribute3="ddd"/>
```

I use this code:

```
hDoc:CREATE-NODE(hAttribute, "MyNode", "ELEMENT").
hAttribute:SET-ATTRIBUTE("MyNode", "aaa").
hAttribute:SET-ATTRIBUTE("Attribute1", "bbb").
hAttribute:SET-ATTRIBUTE("Attribute2", "ccc").
hAttribute:SET-ATTRIBUTE("Attribute3", "ddd").
hNode:APPEND-CHILD(hAttribute).
```

but it keeps creating this messed up output:

```
<MyNode Attribute1="bbb" MyNode="aaa" Attribute2="ccc" Attribute3="ddd"/>
```

Or is it because of the node name and the attribute name is the same? But there has to be a way to put that node-name-attribute to the first place...
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you really need that? "Note that the order of attribute specifications in a start-tag or empty-element tag is not significant." This is according to the specification of xml, chapter 3.1: https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-starttags

Comment: Unfortunatelly, I need. This is a part of a SOAP request and the server require an exact attributes order.

Comment: Start by editing your code so it's runnable... Now it's not and that doesn't help others to help you...

Comment: It's just a part of the code. I tought the var definitions and the other - not related to the problem - parts are not necessary.

Comment: Since you need a couple of more lines to actually make your code run and produce an xml at all I would say its related and necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of XML attributes is insignificant (https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-starttags)

> Note that the order of attribute specifications in a start-tag or
>   empty-element tag is not significant.

Using the DOM parser you have no control over the order - see https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/000034225

If you use the SAX-WRITER - since it is streaming - you are in control of the order:

```
def var lcc as longchar no-undo.
def var hsax as handle no-undo.

create sax-writer hsax.
hsax:set-output-destination( "longchar", lcc ).
hsax:formatted = true.
hsax:start-document().
hsax:start-element( "MyNode" ).
hsax:insert-attribute( "MyNode", "aaa" ).
hsax:insert-attribute( "Attribute1", "bbb" ).
hsax:insert-attribute( "Attribute2", "ccc" ).
hsax:insert-attribute( "Attribute3", "ddd" ).
hsax:end-element( "MyNode" ).
hsax:end-document().

message "sax" skip string( lcc ) skip view-as alert-box.
```

see https://abldojo.services.progress.com:443/#/?shareId=5e1484014b1a0f40c34b8c1f for both